# How can I move a div on hover without repeately triggering it

Tags: html, css, hover, css-animations

So I have a simple animation that makes my html icon to move from left to right on hover in my navbar

Animation and hover does work, but the problem is, when the cursor is hovering over the icon
or class="fire", the hover effect keeps kicking in without fully play out the animation
from left:0px to left:200px.

The most it will go is 50px, and then the animation starts over again from 0 like explained.

How can I hover ONCE and have the icon do one full cycle of animation?

```css
.fire:hover {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="fire"></div>
  <ul class="nav_list_container">
    <li class="nav_list">
      <img class="target" src="https://picsum.com/50">
      <span>ABOUT</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_list">
      <img src="https://picsum.com/50">
      <span>TRUTHS</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_list">
      <img src="https://picsum.com/50">
      <span>PICTURE</span>
    </li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btnControl4" />
    <li class="nav_list">
      <img src="https://picsum.com/50">
      <label>FORM</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your list markup is faulty. An input can't be the child of a list.

Answer (score 1):

Use `width: 100%;`, `padding-left` and `box-sizing: border-box;` instead of relative position and animation on the `left` parameter. Note that I also added `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to let it end on the right side.

```css
.fire {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fire:hover {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    padding-left: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="fire"></div>
  <ul class="nav_list_container">
    <li class="nav_list">
      <img class="target" src="https://picsum.com/50">
      <span>ABOUT</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_list">
      <img src="https://picsum.com/50">
      <span>TRUTHS</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_list">
      <img src="https://picsum.com/50">
      <span>PICTURE</span>
    </li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btnControl4" />
    <li class="nav_list">
      <img src="https://picsum.com/50">
      <label>FORM</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: i had to get my class to be absolute otherwise my whole nav moves, padding left will also move my navbar list itself.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you move the element that you have to hover to make the effect, you can select the container of it to keep the effect without having to follow your element with your mouse.

In my example I chose to use `margin-left` and `transition-duration` (that I applied to the `div` and not `body:hover` so I keep the transition in mouseover and mouseout.

```css
body{
/*height:100vh;*/
  margin:0;
}
div{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:orange;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
body:hover div{
  margin-left:200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```